# Field ... in ... required a bean of type ... that could not be found Error

Tags: java, sql, spring, gradle

I come to you as a last hope, I'm a newbie in programming and I'm having a trouble starting my project using Spring and Gradle. I'm getting an error every time I try to launch my project and I don't understand why...

Here is the error

```
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-10 00:08:24.364  INFO 16456 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-08-10 00:08:24.383  INFO 16456 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-8].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-10 00:08:24.383  INFO 16456 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 221 ms
2022-08-10 00:08:24.388  WARN 16456 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.TechTicketing.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2022-08-10 00:08:24.388  INFO 16456 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-10 00:08:24.393  INFO 16456 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-10 00:08:24.395 ERROR 16456 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.example.TechTicketing.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.example.TechTicketing.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.TechTicketing.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

I searched a lot about this error, but every solutions I found doesn't seem to work, I checked my package disposition it looks fine :

[Package Dispostion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCeuM.png)

I did use the annotations @Service, @RestController, @Entity, @Repository in my classes, I did try to remove the @Autowired, the application starts, but as soon as I do a get request it gives a null pointer so it's basically the same issue... I tried modifying the options in the configuration of my main class but either it doesn't change anything, either it crashes... I tried all the options I found online but I was unable to fix the issue. Here are some of my code.

UserEntity

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="User")
public class UserEntity {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private long IdUser;
     private String Name;
     private String FirstName;
     private String Mail;
     private String Password;
     private String Phone;
     private String Address;
     private String TechCode;
     private int Role;
        @JsonIgnore
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="IdInternalInter")
        private List<InterventionEntity> intervention;
        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="IdRole")
        private RoleEntity role;
}
```

UserRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.TechTicketing.entity.UserEntity;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long>{

}
```

UserController

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.TechTicketing.entity.UserEntity;
import com.example.TechTicketing.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public UserEntity getUserById(@PathVariable("id")final Long id) {
        Optional<UserEntity> user = userService.getUserById(id);
        if(user.isPresent()) {
            return user.get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Iterable<UserEntity> getUsers(){
        return userService.getUsers();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public UserEntity addUser(@RequestBody UserEntity user) {
        return userService.addUser(user);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/updateUser")
    public UserEntity updateUser(@RequestBody UserEntity user) {
        return userService.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

UserService

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.TechTicketing.entity.UserEntity;
import com.example.TechTicketing.repository.UserRepository;

import lombok.Data;

@Service
@Data
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public Optional<UserEntity> getUserById(final Long userID){
        return userRepository.findById(userID);
    }
    
    public Iterable<UserEntity> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    public UserEntity addUser(UserEntity user) {
        UserEntity addedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        return addedUser;
    }
    
    public UserEntity updateUser(UserEntity user){
        UserEntity existingUser = userRepository.findById(user.getIdUser()).orElse(null);
        existingUser.setAddress(user.getAddress());
        existingUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        existingUser.setIntervention(user.getIntervention());
        existingUser.setMail(user.getMail());
        existingUser.setName(user.getName());
        existingUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        existingUser.setPhone(user.getPhone());
        existingUser.setRole(user.getRole());
        existingUser.setTechCode(user.getTechCode());
        return userRepository.save(existingUser);
        
    }
}
```

TechTicketingApp

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

//@ComponentScan("com.example.TechTicketing.repository")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
        exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class TechTicketingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TechTicketingApplication.class, args);
    }
    

}
```

build.gradle

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Please tell me if you need more, I can also eventually provide a link to a github folder if needed ! thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to use a `CrudRepository` judging by what you post with JPA. But you have disabled both the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`. Both are needed to enable JPA and Spring Data JPA. No datasource, no JPA, no repositories hence error during start.

Comment: Thank you ! It's indeed not giving that error anymore ! However I have another one now but I still need to look for an answer first, looks like an sql error now ("
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Le pilote n'a pas pu établir de connexion sécurisée au serveur SQL Server à l'aide du chiffrement SSL (Secure Sockets Layer). Erreur : « PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target »") Thank you for fixing my previous issue ! If I get stuck again I'll post a new question haha

Answer (score -1):

looks like UserRepository is not annotate with @Repository if not spring data
if spring data try to add below

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.TechTicketing.repository") @EntityScan(basePackages="com.example.TechTicketing.entity")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But as you can see I shared the file UserRepository also and I annotated it with @Repository

Comment: try to add your repository package too  in TechTicketingApplication @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.TechTicketing.repository")

@EntityScan(basePackages="com.example.TechTicketing.entity")

Comment: Please don't advice to add `@Repository` to a Spring Data repository it doesn't add anything. Spring Data has different means of detecting the repositories.

Comment: With a Spring Boot application you don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories` so that also doesn't apply. The error is the fact that he excluded the configurations which are needed for JPA to work in the first place.